# Install MSBuild 15 (Microsoft Build tools) without admin rights?

Tags: c#, msbuild

is there any way to install MSBuild 15 on my machine locally without admin rights?

Microsoft's instsaller on https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ seems to inevitably ask for admin rights. I've tried looking into the .exe directly with 7zip, but don't think there's much I could manually extract either (looks like the exe is just a web downloader).

Would there by any other way anyone can think of?

--

Why do I need this? I'm developing on a non-admin machine. I could install the NetCore SDK and VSCode withou admin rights, which is great.
For one of my C# projects I'll need MSBuild to compile though (as I'm trying to use WPF/XAML), specifically MSBuild 15 due to the format of my .csproj files.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else is trying the same, I managed to do it;

started with Nuget package Microsoft.Build.Runtime, extracted its contents + downloaded all dependent packages into the same folder, plus a few more (several Nuget Build related ones, also available on Nuget).

Had to fiddle a bit with dependencies, environment variables (so my non-admin install of the Net Core SDK would be found) + including build tasks manually etc., but works now. In the end, I was able to use VSCode to compile a WPF application targeting .Net 4.6.1 that references a few other NetStandard 2.0 projects.

Comment: I would like to do the same, would you mind sharing more details?

Comment: Few more details would have been nice. Incredibly vague "answer".

Comment: This is not an answer, but an anecdote. Please explain your process.