# Use Cython / Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools without admin rights

Tags: visual-c++, cython

I was looking for ways to interface C++/Qt projects with Python when I decided I might start learning Cython code.
I found [this article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cython.html) from Pycharm's website, saying that the free version does have basic Cython support.
I followed the guide up to the part above the sentence "Once the build task successfully completes, the .so file is created." as the compiler gives an error:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

This problem has been mentioned on multiple stack overflow thread.
The problem is that I can only use my work PC and I do not have admin rights.
An answer has been giving an answer which I did not get where they got the tools from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47794180/14729172

Is it possible to get a detailed answer from how to find a work-around (without admin rights) to install the tool (Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools/Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0), or another tool that allows to run Cython.

I am using latest Pycharm on Python 3.10 on a company Windows 10.

### Edit

I tried the possibility of using mingw to use Cython.
I use mingw's Python 3.9.12.
I used this [tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/cython) (not Pycharm's tutorial anymore).
I created the following file *example.pyx*:

```
from libc.math cimport pow
cdef double square_and_add (double x):
    return pow(x, 2.0) + x
cpdef print_result (double x):
    print("Test")
```

In *setup.py*:

```
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
ext = Extension(name="hello", sources=["example.pyx"])
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(ext))
```

And finally ran:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=mingw32
```

It generated a example.c and a hello.cp39-mingw_x86_64.pyd; which is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned tutorial is certainly for Linux since .so files are typically Linux shared libraries. Cython mostly requires MSVC on Windows. Indeed, the [documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/install.html) states:

> The CPython project recommends building extension modules (including Cython modules) with the same compiler that Python was built with. This is usually a specific version of Microsoft Visual C/C++ (MSVC) - see https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers. **MSVC is the only compiler that Cython is currently tested with on Windows**. A possible alternative is the open source **MinGW** (a Windows distribution of gcc). See the appendix for instructions for setting up MinGW manually.

Put it shortly, you can try with MinGW, but you need to use a MinGW-based CPython to avoid many issues and you could still have some issue due to this configuration not being tested (ie. experimental).

Comment: I actually have MingW installed. Can you provide steps that I can follow to use what you said?

Comment: Did you read the link provided in the quoted documentation ? It provides the steps. Installing MinGW is not sufficient. You need to have a compatible python, configure the PATH and distutils.

Comment: I've tried what you said with mingw, and documented it in the question what I tried and it works. Thank you very much :)